# Highlight particular X and Y coordinations in the iOS charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am very new to the swift. I am trying to bring the exact output as I attached Image.
I am using iOS charts API. I brought up the line charts with all the options, but I need to highlight only the particular X-Y coordinations which are tappable (user clickable)
Anyone, please guide me if you can.

[image: Green graph with yellow and pink highlight points]

Thanks in advance.